# How to turn grayscale image into RGB?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am making a application in python that allows people to share their screens, but in order to get a decent frame rate I wanted to compress the image into a grayscale format and then on the client side turn it back into an RGB image. But when I tried to do that it still showed a grayscale image.

Then I tried using HSV color conversion which did display the color, but with a red filter for some reason.

I won't show all of the code due to the fact it is at least 2000 lines, but I will show what part of the code where I am having my problem.

Server side:

```
sct_img = sct.grab(bounding_box)
img_np = np.array(sct_img)
frame = img_np
frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0,0), fx = 0.70, fy = 0.70)
data = pickle.dumps(frame)
message_size = struct.pack("L", len(data))
clientsocket.sendall(message_size + data)
```

Client side:

```
 frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
 frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
 frame = cv2.resize(frame, (x, y))
 cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
```

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: How do you know it was grayscale?

Comment: Doesn’t converting to grayscale discard the color information?

Comment: so I know that It isnt grey scale because when use cv2.COLOR_BRG2HSV is displays color but with a red filter but when I try and display the image without HSV its still grayscale

Answer (score 2):

When you convert an RGB image to grayscale, color data gets thrown away, hence you won't be able to get the original image back. Observe the output from code below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Create image
img = np.full((500, 500, 3), 255, 'uint8')
cv2.rectangle(img, (50, 100), (250, 300), (0, 0, 96), -1)
cv2.circle(img, (300, 350), 100, (0, 50, 0), -1)
cv2.drawContours(img, [np.array([(300, 50), (200, 250), (400, 250)])], 0, (255, 0, 0), -1)

# Convert to grayscale
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(np.unique(img_gray))

# Show images
cv2.imshow("BGR", img)
cv2.imshow("Gray", img_gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, with the image of a red, green and blue shape *(each a specific shade of its color)*, converting it into grayscale results in the three colors turning into one; `(29, 29, 29)`. There is no way the computer will be able to tell that the three shapes used to be different colors.

Comment: I think the question refers to transforming colour into grayscale not into a simple black and white image as the example here clearly shows. Perhaps if the original question displayed one of the target colour images, other characteristics of each pixel in an rgb colour representation could be mapped to a grayscale. Look at some tutorials like baeldung.com/cs/convert-rgb-to-grayscale for methods to do this.

Comment: There are also ML models capable of going back the other way by generating colour images from gray-scale ones:

"A Novel Approach for Gray Scale Image Colorization using Convolutional Neural Networks," 10.1109/ICSCAN49426.2020.9262377

"Automatic Image Colorization using Ensemble of Deep Convolutional Neural Networks," 10.1109/TENSYMP54529.2022.9864479 

"Intelligent Colorization for Thermal Infrared Image Based on CNN,"  10.1109/ICIBA50161.2020.9277116. 

"A Novel Unbiased Deep Learning Approach in Feature Space for Converting Gray to Color Image,"  10.1109/ACCESS.2023.3263948

Answer (score 0):

When you reduce a color image to grayscale, you're discarding information. There's no way to get color back. If you want to get an acceptable frame rate, you're going to have to choose some other approach.

Comment: In absolute terms, this may be true. However, there are recent techniques (2020 to 2023 as of this writing) to infer colour from a gray-scale image. They are not perfect but they could work for some use cases. The drive for this research seems to be able to use single thermal camera systems for 24-hour object detection but to display a colourized version for human consumption (for reporting and alarm confirmation mainly).